# Xcode 6 : many choices for a physical device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

In Xcode 6 (and previous), for a Scheme I can choose between Simulators and physical device to run. I've iOS 8.1 and 7.1 simulators installed.

When I plug my iPhone 6 to my Mac, it appears 3 times in this list, like this : `iPhone_Name (8.1 (12B411), iPhone 6, arm64, iPhone_identifier)`

What is the difference between them ?
I know that it's not exactly the same, some errors or log messages appear when I choose the first in the list but not the two others.

Typically, I've a bug with an `UIActivityViewController` size that appear only when I choose the two first in the list.

Maybe it can help : My app has a Deployment Target for iOS 7.0.